# sync incoming midi events with outgoing coreaudio output

Tags: ios, core-audio, coremidi

I'm trying to write a basic sequencer for ios, using something like iConnectMIDI and a synth controller for input.  I need to be able to receive MIDI events (note on/off) and compare their timestamps to a stable click track I have running at a known bpm.  Say I have this click track as an mp3 file that loops infinitely...how would I go about relating the incoming timestamps to the millisecond-onset of this mp3 file ( as heard by the listener -- accounting for any latency that may occur on the output end )?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the RemoteIO Audio Unit to play raw samples of your click track, and know the sample number within your click that you wish to use to mark your click sound, you can the Audio Session output latency to estimate the offset from media timestamps of the audio unit buffer callbacks.